# Issue Migrating from VM to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, .net-core

I have a VM set up with a published .net core app. Works awesome.

I've now migrated over to Azure and I am setting up the Azure App environment properly to the best of my knowledge. I've migrated all of my files over to the appropriate locations, but my application is not loading with a 502.5 Error.

I have no idea what could be causing this, but I can say that I have not changed any settings in the appsettings.json or web.config so the original settings are still there. I am actually not sure what I am supposed to change them to.

Example:

Any direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Was helped from someone on .net slack.

When you migrate to Azure App Service, make sure you edit the web.config file to change the arguements of processpath and log.

```
aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments="D:\home\site\wwwroot\

stdoutLogFile="d:\home\LogFiles\"
```